# Tracing a syntax error in my PHP code

Tags: php

Can you find the error please? I'd really appreciate it.

I think it's the curly brackets but I don't know where. I'm doing this to echo username in their profile. for example `<? echo $username; ?>` I haven't tested the echo because I'm getting a syntax error.

```
     <?php
        // check for errors
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set('display_errors', True);

        // deny access if not logged
        if (!session_id()) session_start();
        if (!$_SESSION['logon']){ 
            header("Location:login.php");
            die();
        }
        $username = $_POST['username'];  //martin
        $password = $_POST['password']; //123456
            if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
        {   
            // connect to server
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            if(!$con){
                die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());}
            mysql_select_db("test", $con);
            if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")))

{
         //Correct information
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if (!$result) {
               die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
            }
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

            $expire = time()+60*60*24*30;//1 month
            setcookie("id", $row['id'], $expire);

            mysql_close($con);
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: You tried nothing to find a syntax error. Why should we?

Comment: I mean this site is meant to help?

Comment: @MartinNewAtCode This site favors questions which are usefull to others. It's very unlikly that someon who has a similiar problem will stumble across your question.

Comment: You are missing `{` after `while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

Comment: Hi @Martin. If you use something like NetBeans, Eclipse or PHPStorm, it will indicate for you where syntax errors are.

Comment: thanks @halfer appreciated

Comment: No worries. Also, to avoid downvotes here, show research or prior work, and avoid asking not to be downvoted in the question. To trace code problems, one approach is to comment out things block-by-block until it works, and then introduce things again until it breaks. That will help identify the area of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
  <?php
    // check for errors
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', True);

    // deny access if not logged
    if (!session_id()) session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['logon']){ 
        header("Location:login.php");
        die();
    }
    $username = $_POST['username'];  //martin
    $password = $_POST['password']; //123456
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) 
    {   
        // connect to server
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        if(!$con){
            die('Could not connect: '. mysql_error());}
        mysql_select_db("test", $con);
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'")))

{
     //Correct information
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users where username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        if (!$result) {
           die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {

        $expire = time()+60*60*24*30;//1 month
        setcookie("id", $row['id'], $expire);
        }

        mysql_close($con);
        }


        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Could you just post what you changed and explain your changes?

Comment: hey I fixed my syntax by messing with it. thanks tho

Comment: Welcome...You missed with Closing brackets...Please mark this as answer...

Comment: @user3244721, I agree with Jimmy - a block of code to try doesn't indicate what the problem is. Some people do a before-and-after, which seems to work well, but above all a description of the issue is most useful.